# Spawning a second robot using the clearpath_gz simulation

Tags: gazebo, ros2, husky, clearpath

- OS:  Ubuntu 22.04
- ROS 2 Distro: Humble
- Built from source or installed: Installed followin this : https://docs.clearpathrobotics.com/docs/ros/tutorials/simulator/install

**Expected behaviour**
I am launching a simulation using

`ros2 launch clearpath_gz simulation.launch.py rviz:=true setup_path:=$HOME/clearpath/cp1`

and spawning an additional robot using

`ros2 launch clearpath_gz robot_spawn.launch.py setup_path:=$HOME/clearpath/cp5`

And I should expect a robot completely working.

**Actual behaviour**
I cannot drive the second robot.

The simulation give the following error messages:
`[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1704465289.453031469] [a200_0005.controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'joint_state_broadcaster'. [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1704465289.533124046] [a200_0005.controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'platform_velocity_controller'.`

And the spawner:

```
[spawner-5] [FATAL] [1704465289.454854305] [a200_0005.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed loading controller joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-6] [FATAL] [1704465289.536445595] [a200_0005.spawner_platform_velocity_controller]: Failed loading controller platform_velocity_controller
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 138988, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager-timeout 60 joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args -r __ns:=/a200_0005'].
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 138990, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager-timeout 60 platform_velocity_controller --ros-args -r `__ns:=/a200_0005'].
```

**To Reproduce**
Provide the steps to reproduce:

1. Follow the installation tutorials
2. Create a folder for each robot in -/clearpath/ (cp1 and cp5)
3. Copy the example robot.yaml to each folder and change the serial number, host : self, and namespace to a200-0001 or 5.

```
serial_number: a200-0001
version: 0
system:
  username: administrator
  hosts:
    self: cpr-a200-0001
    platform:
      cpr-a200-0000: 192.168.131.1
    onboard: {}
    remote: {}
  ros2:
    namespace: a200_0001
    domain_id: 0
    rmw_implementation: rmw_fastrtps_cpp
    workspaces: []
platform:
  controller: ps4
  battery:
    model: ES20_12C
    configuration: S2P1
  attachments:
    - name: front_bumper
      type: bumper
      parent: front_bumper_mount
    - name: rear_bumper
      type: bumper
      parent: rear_bumper_mount
    - name: top_plate
      type: top_plate
      model: pacs
    - name: sensor_arch
      type: sensor_arch
      parent: default_mount
      model: sensor_arch_300
      enabled: true
  extras:
    urdf: null
    ros_parameters:
      platform_velocity_controller:
        linear.x.max_velocity": 1.0
        linear.x.min_velocity": -1.0
        linear.x.max_acceleration": 3.0
        linear.x.min_acceleration": -3.0
        angular.z.max_velocity": 2.0
        angular.z.min_velocity": -2.0
        angular.z.max_acceleration": 6.0
        angular.z.min_acceleration": -6.0
links:
  box:
  - name: user_bay_cover
    parent: default_mount
    xyz: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0075]
    rpy: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    size: [0.4, 0.4, 0.002]
  cylinder: []
  frame: []
  mesh: []
  sphere: []
mounts:
  bracket:
  - parent: top_plate_mount_d1
    xyz: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    rpy: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    model: horizontal
  fath_pivot:
  - parent: sensor_arch_mount
    xyz: [0.0, 0.0, -0.021]
    rpy: [3.1415, 0.0, 0.0]
    angle: 0.0
  riser: []
  disk: []
  post: []
sensors:
  camera:
  - model: intel_realsense
    urdf_enabled: true
    launch_enabled: true
    parent: fath_pivot_0_mount
    xyz: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    rpy: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ros_parameters:
      camera:
        camera_name: camera_0
        device_type: d435
        serial_no: '0'
        enable_color: true
        rgb_camera.profile: 640,480,30
        enable_depth: true
        depth_module.profile: 640,480,30
        pointcloud.enable: true
  gps: []
  imu: []
  lidar2d:
  - model: hokuyo_ust
    urdf_enabled: true
    launch_enabled: true
    parent: bracket_0_mount
    xyz: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    rpy: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ros_parameters:
      urg_node:
        laser_frame_id: lidar2d_0_laser
        ip_address: 192.168.131.20
        ip_port: 10940
        angle_min: -3.141592653589793
        angle_max: 3.141592653589793
  lidar3d:
  - model: velodyne_lidar
    urdf_enabled: true
    launch_enabled: true
    parent: sensor_arch_mount
    xyz: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    rpy: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ros_parameters:
      velodyne_driver_node:
        frame_id: lidar3d_0_laser
        device_ip: 192.168.131.25
        port: 2368
        model: VLP16
      velodyne_transform_node:
        model: VLP16
        fixed_frame: lidar3d_0_laser
        target_frame: lidar3d_0_laser
```

5 - Launch the simulation with
`ros2 launch clearpath_gz simulation.launch.py rviz:=true setup_path:=$HOME/clearpath/cp1`

6 - Spawn a robot with

`ros2 launch clearpath_gz robot_spawn.launch.py setup_path:=$HOME/clearpath/cp5`

7- use teleop to drive to drive the robot 5, not working

```
ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard cmd_vel:=/a200_0005/cmd_vel
```